# Horizontal line after removing the border of a JButton

Tags: java

So in the image below im using a 6x6 BorderLayout with 6x6 JButtons in it. I wanted to remove the border completly and used

```
button.setBorder(null);
```

But as you see theres still a horizontal line, is there a way to remove that one?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change the background of your buttons ?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: It works when i change the color, i guess thats just the default texture which causes that "horizontal line".

Comment: The default button background is a gradient. It is not a line, it is a shear color difference between the light and dark edge of the button.